# C# Reading from XML files

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing an application that reads from XML files. But I am having a probling. My XML file looks like this:

```
<variable>
  <varName>Love</varName>
  <type>int</type>
  <value>0</value>
</variable>
```

And I am reading it like this:

```
XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
xmldoc.Load(fs);
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("variable");
for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    Variable elem = new Variable();

    for (int j = 0; j < xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Count; j++)
    {
        if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).Name == "varName")
            elem.varName = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText;

        if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).Name == "type")
        {
            if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText == "int")
                elem.type = VariableType.INT;

            if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText == "bool")
                elem.type = VariableType.BOOL;
        }

        if (xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).Name == "value")
            elem.value = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText;
    }
}
```

After this code I should have got my `elem.name="Love"` `elem.value=0` `elem.type=INT`
But instead I have four  `elem` variables first having values I want others with `type="INT"` others (name, value) =null. Any IDEAS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd strongly advise you to use LINQ to XML - it makes all of this *much* simpler.

Comment: I have already 1000 lines of code. It takes me a lot. I need to correct this one.

Comment: This should be easy to find out if you step through your code with the debugger and keep checking the values of your elem properties.

Comment: I don't see an `el` variable or a `.name` property, did you post the code you ran?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis I think Bundler means elem...

Comment: Sorry it was elem!

Comment: @Bungler you should read the documentation on .NET and XML. It explains how to use XmlSerializer or the more recent XDocument classes. You can generate the appropriate classes from your XSD. There's no reason to work with raw elements. There's no reason to work *without* an XSD either

Comment: @Bungler I was asking whether you ran the exact code you posted, because that code in combination with exactly that xml snippet, produces _one_ `elem` with all three properties set.

Comment: @Bungler does your file have an XSD?

Comment: C.Evenhuis. It is the code which I compiled. It give to some times correct result. Last time for example I made a variabel named "new1" and it worked perfectly. I dont understand what is happining.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly it would be worth your while learning LINQ to XML. It's much easier and wouldn't take long to refactor your 1000 lines.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, VariableType>()
{
    { "int", VariableType.INT },
    { "bool", VariableType.BOOL },
};

var variables =
    XDocument
        .Load("fname")
        .Root
        .Elements("variable")
        .Select(x => new Variable()
        {
            varName = x.Element("varName").Value,
            type = map[x.Element("type").Value.ToLower()],
            value = x.Element("value").Value,
        })
        .ToList();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

at first you need an object like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "variable")]
public class Variable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "varName")]
    public string VarName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }

}
```

then deserilize your XML like this:

```
var result = XmlDeserializer<Variable>(File.ReadAllText("your path"));
```

note:
here is my custom XML deserilzer:

```
public static T XmlDeserializer<T>(string xmlString)
{
    var instance = default(T);
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var stringreader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        instance = (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringreader);

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some documentation for XML deserializer or serializer. I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @Bungler If your first instinct on seeing something new is to ask on Stack Overflow, then you're wrong. Research first. XmlSerializer is part of the .NET Framework, you can find plenty of documentation about it. Just do a web search for "XmlSerializer msdn"

Comment: @Bungler that's the plain-old XmlSerializer class used in .NET since 2002. Did you *read* the docs? MSDN has chapters dedicated to it, there are hundreds of articles and is used by ASMX and WCF web services. It's a *fundamental* class

Comment: dear @Bungler here you can read about it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize(v=vs.110).aspx